# Moving certain rows of a text file into a new one using shell

Tags: unix, awk

I have a tab delimited text file like

file 1

```
x1 23 47 59
x2 58 23 12
x3 39 30 11
...
x21909 020
```

and a simple list of values like

file 2

```
x1
x34
x56
x123
..
x9876
```

I'd like to take all of the rows in file 1 beginning with the values in file 2 and move them into a file 3, such that..

file 3

```
x1 23 47 69
x34 38 309 20
x56 49 201 10
x123 39 30 10
..
x9876 48 309 123
```

I've tried using the grep command but I'm not sure how to do it with a long list of values in file 2, and how to make it take the entire row. Is there a simple shell command which could do this?

Comment: What options did you use for `grep` and how did it fail?

Comment: Unless you post some research attempts, you cannot get much assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

With tabs as the delimiter, this should work:

> for i in `cat file2`; do grep -P "^$i\t" file1; done

And with spaces as the delimiter, something like this should work:

> for i in `cat file2`; do grep "^$i " file1; done

Cheers.

Comment: This is an unnecessary use of `cat` and should not be recommended. Refer `Bash Pitfalls`, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: This will fail in various ways given various contents of the 2 files. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} {print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13279488)

Comment: There is a good chance that the OP doesn't even know what `awk` is and how it can be leveraged to solve his problem, and that means that there's a chance that anyone with a similar issue that stumbles upon this answer might not either.  There is nothing wrong with providing a short description that explains this.  A good answer doesn't require someone to look up additional resources in order to understand what the answer is suggesting. There's a reason why your answer appeared in the Low-Quality review queue in the first place.

Comment: Actually, it appeared there because Stack Overflow automatically flags short answers and code-only answers as low-quality.  Yours happened to be both - so I'm not surprised it landed in my review queue.  I'm not trying to say that your answer was bad, just that it can be improved.  Any amount of explanation, even just a simple description of what `awk` is and why it should be used for this problem can go a long way.  If someone with a slightly different problem finds this answer, it won't help them at all - but if a small amount of explanation were included, it might help them figure it out.

Comment: A good explanation for this viewpoint can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146866)

Comment: Honestly, it was just a suggestion, and I'm having a really hard time seeing the viewpoint that there is absolutely no way that your answer can be improved, but I respect your opinion.  You seem very bitter about the whole thing - kinda seems like you've had a bad day or something.  I'll leave this alone.

Comment: The point of Review is to recommend deletion of answers that appear to be low quality.  When you recommend deletion, you have the option of picking from a few comments that you can automatically leave to help the poster improve the quality of their future answers.  Instead of using one of those, I opted to use a different comment to address why I felt this post was low-quality.  My suggestion was to include more information so that the long-term value of the answer could be improved.  Also, the OP never asked for a solution using any particular tool.  Not sure where you got that from.

Comment: [That was added by someone else, not the original poster.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38849745/revisions)  Regardless if I'm familiar with the tool or not, the premise is the same - your answer would have more long-term value for other users who find this question later on if you included some explanation.

Comment: Again - you are completely wrong and you are not qualified to judge whether this answer is low quality or not, never mind recommending it be deleted. The fact that a tool flags brief answers or answers without explanation as possibly being low quality does not mean that they are. You need to read and understand the answer to make that determination - that's why the tool just flags it rather than deleting it. If you want to review flagged answers then go ahead but please stick to areas you know something about and don't apply sweeping dogma across all answers you review.

Answer (score 0):

if the first field values are distinct from the rest of the fields, grep fits the bill

```
grep -Ff file2 file1
```